# How to create a category and a channel using python discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a function that first creates a category called "management", then it creates a channel named after the member count of my server.

The expected outcome is that the category and channel gets created accordingly as explained above.

This is the code i am trying to use

```
@client.command()
async def setup_counter(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send("Setting up management!")
        await guild.create_category("Management", overwrites=None, reason=None)
        await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Member Count: {guild.member_count}", overwrites=None, category="Management", reason=None)
        await ctx.send("Setup finished!")
    except Exception as errors:
        print(f"Bot Error: {errors}")
```

Comment: What happens instead of your desired result?

Comment: @JakobF I get an error saying ```Bot Error: name 'guild' is not defined```

Comment: Somewhere you have to declare which server (Guild) you want to do this in. On that object you can call `create_category`.

Comment: @JakobF How would i be able to declare that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select on which server (Guild) you want to do that. Additonally you need to pass a reference to the category not just the name of it. If you know the id of your guild, use this:

```py
@client.command()
async def setup_counter(ctx):
    try:
        guild = client.get_guild(id) # <-- insert yor guild id here
        await ctx.send("Setting up management!")
        category = await guild.create_category("Management", overwrites=None, reason=None)
        await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Member Count: {guild.member_count}", overwrites=None, category=category, reason=None)
        await ctx.send("Setup finished!")
    except Exception as errors:
        print(f"Bot Error: {errors}")
```

If you dont know the guild id just follow this official [article](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) where they discuss finding the server id.

Comment: When i do this.

Comment: The category gets created. but the channel does not get created. and i get this error: 
```Bot Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'```

Comment: Can u show me the line in which you put in your guild id?

Comment: guild = client.get_guild(669599213264306206)

Answer (score 0):

use `ctx.guild` in the places where you are using `guild.#something` No need to use `guild = client.get_guild()`.